# How to specify an templatized alias' generic type in a container

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, polymorphism, type-erasure

I have a class Task:

```
template <typename T>
class Task {

    Task(const std::function<T()>& func) 
        : m_func(func)
    {
        // some stuff here
    }

    std::shared_ptr<T> getValue() {
        return m_value;
    }

    void execute() {
        m_value = std::make_shared<T>(m_func());
    }


    std::shared_ptr<T> m_value;  
    std::function<T()> m_func;  
}
```

Now, I want to alias this Task class to a shared_ptr so I do the following...

`template <typename T> using TaskPtr = std::shared_ptr<Task<T> >;`

I have another class that will store a container of of TaskPtr, I would like for the consumer of the api to specify T when calling addTask as follows.

```
Class X {
    // some boiler plate code
    template <typename T> 
    addTask(TaskPtr<T> task) {
         m_queue.push(task);
    }

    void loop() {
        // do some stuff
        auto item = m_queue.front();
        item->execute();
        m_queue.pop();
        // continue looping
    }

 std::queue<TaskPtr<T> > m_queue; 
}
```

I was wondering what the best way to do this would be. This code gives me the error that T is undefined. Duh! I need to add `template <tyepname T>` above my `m_queue` definition, that makes sense. When I do that, I get that I am putting the keyword `typedef` in an incorrect location. When I remove the template declaration and the `T` to just have `std::queue<Taskptr> m_queue;`, it tells me I am missing a template argument. Which makes sense, except I don't understand where it should go.

I have searched for an answer and couldn't find anything. What is the correct syntactical implementation for what I am trying do?

Comment: "I need to add template <tyepname T> above my m_queue definition" - no: you have to add `template <typename T>` above your `Class X` definition

Comment: @max66, Hi Max thanks for the reply. My issue here is that I don't want X to be templatized. Just the TaskPtr, I'm not sure if that makes sense.T could be different for each TaskPtr in m_queue.

Comment: As far I know, do not make sense. Starting from C++14 you can define template variables, but not template variables as members inside a classes (you need to know the size of a class; you can't do it with a template member)

Comment: And no: you can't have object of different types inside the same `std::queue`

Comment: @max66 The objects inside the queue are all shared_ptr to a Task object. That Task object is stores a template private variable which would be defined on addTask via `addTask(TaskPtr<int>)`, is that not possible?

Comment: we don't see how you use `Task` execution result. should we assume you don't use it at all?

Comment: To put tasks into an `std::queue` of `std::shared_ptr`s, you should derive `Task<T>` from a non-template `Task_base` and then make `std:queue` of `std::shared_ptr<Task_base>`s. You can't have an `std::queue` with heterogeneous types.

Comment: @AndriyTylychko when you call execute. Task will just store the result of the std::function (as seen in my post), then the user can call getValue() to get the result. What the user does with that result is up to them.

Comment: @Evgeny: I suppose you propose `Task_base` to have something like `virtual GetValue()` method? what would be its signature?

Comment: @Evgeny huh, I really would prefer to not go down the rabbit hole of inheritance, but I guess if there is no other way...

Comment: Class `X` cannot contain an infinite number of members, one for every possible type `T`.

Comment: I believe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVGtNFg4ay0 will help.

Comment: @AndriyTylychko, it should be redesigned somehow. Now I see that OP is trying to put elements of different types into an `std::queue`. That's not possible. In the general case some type of polymorphism is need, e.g., via inheritance or via type erasure.

Comment: @Evgeny I'm open to a redesign. I am pretty new to C++ and have never worked with templates before, I thought this was what they were for, but I understand the problem (compiler needs to know how much memory to allocate).

Comment: Templates offer, so to speak, a compile-time polymorphism. If you need run-time polymorphism, templates alone won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is at:

```
class X {
   ....
   std::queue<TaskPtr<T> > m_queue;  // <--- T is unknown
};
```

At that point, the compiler wants to know what is the type of the task, but you want simply to store all tasks regardless to their type. To figure out how to make this work, look at the uses of `T` and see how to get rid of it.

```
template <typename T>
class Task {
    std::shared_ptr<T> getValue() {
        return m_value;
    }

    void execute() {
        m_value = std::make_shared<T>(m_func());
    }
....
};
```

Had it been only `execute` then life would have been simple, sine the caller of `execute()` does not care what `T` is, only that the operation is executed. If it were only that, then the solution would have been trivial:

```
class TaskBase
{
public:
    virtual ~TaskBase() = default;
    TaskBase(const TaskBase &) = default; // and so on....

    virtual void execute() = 0;
};
template <typename T>
class Task : public TaskBase {
....
};
```

Then, simply store a pointer to `TaskBase` instead of to `Task<T>`.

Solving the `getValue()` is slightly more involved. You need to use dynamic cast from TaskBase to the actual Task from `getValue<T>()`:

```
template <typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> Task<T>::getValue() {
    return m_value;
}

template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T> TaskBase::getValue()
{
    auto childThis = dynamic_cast<Task<T>*>(this);
    if (childThis == nullptr) {
        // or maybe throw an exception
        return nullptr;
    }
    return childThis->getValue();
}
```

The use is more tricky, since the user has to know what type is stored in the task:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<TaskBase> ptr) 
{
    auto ifInt = ptr->getValue<int>();
    auto ifDouble = ptr->getValue<double>();
    ... more code ..
}
```

In this case `Task<int>` would be detected by `ifInt`, but with `Task<unsigned>` this would fail since `ifInt==nullptr`.

---

Apparently the above explanation is not clear enough, so here is the complete source that compiles and works:

```
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
class TaskBase
{
public:
    virtual ~TaskBase() = default;
    TaskBase() = default;
    TaskBase(const TaskBase &) = default; // and so on....
    virtual void execute() = 0;
    template <typename T> 
    std::shared_ptr<T> getValue();
};
template <typename T>
class Task : public TaskBase {
public:
    Task(const std::function<T()>& func) 
        : m_func(func)
    {
        // some stuff here
    }    

    void execute() override {
        m_value = std::make_shared<T>(m_func());
    }  
    std::shared_ptr<T> getValue() {
        return m_value;
    }
private:
std::shared_ptr<T> m_value;  
    std::function<T()> m_func;  
};

template <typename T> 
std::shared_ptr<T> TaskBase::getValue()
{
   auto downCast = dynamic_cast<Task<T>*>(this);
   if (downCast)
       return downCast->getValue();
   else
       return nullptr;
}

using TaskPtr = std::shared_ptr<TaskBase>;
class X {
    // some boiler plate code
public:    
    void addTask(TaskPtr task) {
         m_queue.push(task);
    }

    void loop() {
        // do some stuff
        auto item = m_queue.front();
        item->execute();
        m_queue.pop();
        // continue looping
    }

std::queue<TaskPtr> m_queue; 
};
int main()
{  
   X x;
   TaskPtr task = std::make_shared<Task<int>>(
             [] { std::cout << "int task execution\n"; return 5;});

   x.addTask(task);
   x.loop();
   std::cout << "getValue<int> --> ";
   auto valPtr = task->getValue<int>();
   if (valPtr)
      std::cout << *valPtr << '\n';
   else
      std::cout << "nullptr\n";   
   std::cout << "getValue<float> --> ";
   auto valPtr2 = task->getValue<float>();
   if (valPtr2)
      std::cout << *valPtr2 << '\n';
   else
      std::cout << "nullptr\n";   
}
```

Comment: It smells like `std::any`.

Comment: @Evgeny you are correct, it resembles `std::any`, but with the addition of `execute()`.

Comment: Thanks very much for your in depth response. What an intricate solution for something that (at first) seemed so simple. I appreciate you taking the time to write this out.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Rather, `std::any getValue()`; move the dynamic type code into a type designed for a dynamic type.  Yours ties the derived class of `TaskBase` to the implementation of `TaskBase` among other sins.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont I thought about it, and I believe that a solution with `std::any` will be more complicated, because `TaskBase` and `Task<T>` are still required due to `execute()`. The additional type either causes dynamic allocation on every call to getValue(), or has to be stored somewhere, which has a potential to, either complicates `execute`, or require data duplication. I am not sure this is worth it.

Comment: @MichaelVeksler I'm having an issue. Due to the fact that TaskBase pure virtual execute cannot be a template method, Task execute does not match that of TaskBase, and thus doesn't override it. IE `void Task<T>::execute() != virtual void Task::execute()`

Comment: @hromer I don't see how that can happen. In order to make things 100% clear, I have added to the answer a complete source code that works.

Comment: @hromer you can try it out on https://wandbox.org/permlink/bJxEUD13jbcyFIPe

Comment: @MichaelVeksler The error was elsewhere thank you. Unfortunately my compiler was spitting like 50 lines of errors (and directing me to the wrong file/line), to what was actually a really simple solution. I appreciate your help.